# Json.NET IsValid with schema passing even though not matching

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

I have a json schema in draft-03. One of the properties in it is like this  -

```
"KeyToCheck": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": "true",
        "properties": {
          "property1": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": "true"
          },
          "property2": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": "true"
          },
          "property3": {
            "type": "number",
            "required": "true"
          },
          "property4": { "type": "array" }
        }
      },
      "required": "true"
    }
```

I have applied required - true for KeyToCheck( the bottom most required-true in the above json. However IsValid method is still passing even though KeyToCheck array is coming empty in Response. The method is used in this way - Jtoken.parse(response).isvalid(schema).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, in your JSON schema you do not validate the length of the `KeyToCheck` array. You could use `minItems` property to set the lower bound of an array. Try following JSON schema. Hope it will work.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "KeyToCheck": {
      "type": "array",
      "required": true,
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": true,
        "properties": {
          "property1": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
          },
          "property2": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
          },
          "property3": {
            "type": "number",
            "required": true
          },
          "property4": {
            "type": "array"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Input JSON:

```
{
 "KeyToCheck":[]
}
```

Validation result:

> Message:
>   Array item count 0 is less than minimum count of 1.
>   Schema path:
>    #/properties/KeyToCheck/minItems

**Edit:**

To validate for nonempty array use this schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "KeyToCheck": {
      "type": "array",
      "required": true,
      "maxItems": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Input JSON:

```
{
 "KeyToCheck":["test_value"]
}
```

Validation result:

> Message:
>   Array item count 1 exceeds maximum count of 0.
>   Schema path:
>    #/properties/KeyToCheck/maxItems

Comment: in my case , the problem is that thearray KeyToCheck should actually come empty. but the fact that required true doesn't fail it is the problem. Should I then use maxItems:0 for this? To be sure that there are no items in KeyToCheck array?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about your requirement now. Do you want to pass validation when KeyToCheck array is empty? Further, the `required` keyword has nothing to do with the array size. It validates only the availability of the JSON field and it will fail only when `KeyToCheck` field not available in JSON input.

Comment: so what I want is in that particular response , KeyToCheck array should be empty. So I was just checking once by accident that required:true would fail it , but it didn't. that had me worried. I thought required:true would check that there is atleast one object in the array. So to reframe my question - how do I make sure array is empty in response and fail validation if its not? Sorry, for the confusion.

Comment: Then you could use `"maxItems": 0` for this validation. But note that then `items` definitions in the schema will make no sense so you should probably remove them.

Comment: Ok , so if I do not have 'items' definition , then will it fail if KeyToCheck is not empty?

Comment: Yes. You could test your schema here. https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/